# Which callback always execute in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

We have various callbacks in ruby on rails like `before_validation`, `after_validation`, `before_save`, `after_save` etc. But is there any callback which always  execute in ruby on rails?

Comment: Callbacks run after events. 'Always run' doesn't make sense.

Comment: you can use `before_action` and make your own action

Comment: @G.B you confuse `ActionController` filters with `ActiveRecord` callbacks.

Comment: There's an `after_initialize` callback that's called whenever an object is instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very comprehensive callback is `after_initialize`

This is run for every record that is retrieved from the database, at the time it's retrieved from the database... and is even run when you instantiate a new record (e.g. `Model.new`)

If you use `after_find` it behaves similarly except that it doesn't run against new objects, only on retrieving existing objects.